# Summary RMSE in xtoos_t function

Tags: forecasting, panel-data, stata

It is not clear to me what is the meaning of the Summary RMSE. I thought this would be average of the two out of sample periods but it is not.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The summary is not plain average but weighted average. The weights are number of the observations.